# what does "+" mean in CSS?

Tags: css

```
.competence{+line-height:20px;}
```

I know with * is a CSS hack for IE. Only IE7 and below http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

I want to know what does "+" mean?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the site you linked to: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

> Although Internet Explorer 7 corrected its behavior when a property name is prefixed with an underscore or a hyphen, other non-alphanumeric character prefixes are treated as they were in IE6.

The `+` character counts as "other non-alphanumeric character" and therefore it would be "treated as they were in IE6".

I'd guess that it's a variant of the `*` hack (`*property: value`).

The more conventional use of `+` is in selectors: [see the w3c for details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: Nice catch! This is similar to IE understanding both !important and !doggy as important override.

Comment: @easwee - You can use `!doggy`? That's awesome... I'm going to look that up.

Comment: Basically u can use any word instead of important - it's because of how IE7 and under handles errors in css - see fiddle in ie7 and in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/TrJpS/14/ sweet for when you have to show your anger because someone made you debug for IE :)

Answer (score -1):

Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Thus, the following rule states that when a P element immediately follows a MATH element, it should not be indented:

```
math + p { text-indent: 0 }
```